# In bash profile, is there an option to stop on 1st error on any command?

Tags: error-handling, exit, bash

I'd like to use something like 'set -e' in my bashrc/zshrc so that any time I launch a command it'll stop on first error and return to the prompt as opposed to continue executing the rest of the command.

However using 'set -e' in a bashrc/zshrc profile doesn't work as it'll exit the terminal session (instead of returning to the prompt) whenever I enter a command with an error (eg diff file.txt file.txt which returns non-zero)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't behaving as you expect is because running a script launches a subshell, with its own environment. Running single commands from the command prompt will exit on error, but scripts will sometimes continue on. I am assuming you are talking about running scripts.

Please read the information at the following link: [How "Exit Traps" Can Make Your Bash Scripts Way More Robust And Reliable](http://redsymbol.net/articles/bash-exit-traps/)

Using a function as outlined on that page, and then setting the trap in your script will increase the likelihood that your script will exit cleanly, in the event of error. It will even run the cleanup function if you CTRL-C out of the script!

Make sure you put the set -e in each script also.

Additionally, this page covers some of the same material, plus more: [Writing Robust Bash Shell Scripts](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts/)

Hope this helps